# chapter title layout

Tags: fonts, dimensions

I am trying to define the first page of the chapter.
At the moment I have been able to do this:

[image]

but I can't increase the dimension of the name of the chapter and I would like to put a blue line that start from the bottom of the blue square till the left margin of the page.

Someone know how can I solve these two problems?

here the code:

```
\DeclareFixedFont{\chapternumberfont}{T1}{ppl}{}{}{7.5cm}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\fontsize{40}{75}\selectfont\normalfont\fontfamily{georgia}\selectfont\bfseries\color{cyan}}{
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \path let \p1 = (current page.west), \p2 = (current page.east) in
              node[minimum width=8cm, minimum height=7cm, rectangle, fill=cyan, anchor=north east, align=left, text width=8cm] at ($(current page.north east)$) {
                \begin{textblock*}{7cm}(0.3cm,-3.5cm)
                    \tikz \node [white,text width=8cm, align=left, font=\sffamily] {{\raisebox{4cm}{\Huge\bfseries\sffamily \chaptertitlename}} %\raisebox{-12pt}
                    {\chapternumberfont \thechapter}};
                \end{textblock*}
              };
       \path let \p1 = (current page.west), \p2 = (current page.east) in
              node[minimum width=\x2-\x1, minimum height=0.8in, rectangle, , anchor=south west, align=left, text width=\x2-\x1] at ($(current page.south west)$) {page \thepage};
\end{tikzpicture}
}{-1.75in}{}[\vspace*{1in}]
```